# How to show my spring application into the internet?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I developing spring application and now I want to deploy it into the web.

But how to do this?

Link and answers should help me!

Comment: Search engines are good with links!

Comment: what I should search?

Comment: “deploy spring application”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to purchase a public IP address for your computer if you need your computer to act as a server.
2. Purchase a VPS Hosting Server to host you application.
3. Try to find any good Java Web Hosting servers through search engines.
4. Try open source website like **redhat cloud** to host your webapplication using Git.